# Concatenation in CASE WHEN expression

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, case, string-concatenation

I wanted to check if all the `table_name`s to be created are existing. If they already exist, we need to drop them first.

This is the logic that I've created, this is my first time to `CONCAT` using `CASE WHEN`.

The error here is that `CONCAT` cannot be read in `CASE WHEN`.

Is there any other way to check if table names are existing? Or is there a way to proceed with this logic with suggestions of to fix this?

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;    
DECLARE 
    v_bs_drop_table VARCHAR2(50); 
    v_ebi_drop_table VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE LOWER(table_name) LIKE 'mpiat_after_bs_%')
        LOOP  
            CASE rec.table_name
                WHEN 'mpiat_after_bs_' || SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'ddmonyy'), 3, 5) || '_t'
                    THEN
                        v_bs_drop_table := 'DROP TABLE ' || 'mpiat_after_bs_' || SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'ddmonyy'), 3, 5) || '_t';
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_bs_drop_table);
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_bs_drop_table;  
                WHEN 'mpiat_after_bs_ebi_' || SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'ddmonyy'), 3, 5) || '_t'
                    THEN
                        v_ebi_drop_table := 'DROP TABLE ' || 'mpiat_after_bs_ebi_' || SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'ddmonyy'), 3, 5) || '_t';
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_ebi_drop_table);
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_ebi_drop_table;   
                ELSE 
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO EXISTING TABLE NAMES');
            END CASE;
        END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: please don't write in all caps

Comment: `SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'ddmonyy'), 3, 5)` <--- Why?

Comment: Tagged your DBMS as Oracle for you, Oracle supports [IF...THEN...ELSE](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php)

Comment: Everyone here are always ready to help you only if respect us. Please don't SHOUT at us.

Comment: Apologies for the all caps. Thank you for making it readable.

Comment: Actually a case _statement_. (Lots of people call case expression for statement, but this was the first time I've seen the other way.)

Comment: SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'ddmonyy'), 3, 5) <--- Why?                        
 --->Because I need to get the month and year.

Answer (score 0):

Use IF..THEN..ELSE instead

Also, `substr(to_char(sysdate,'ddmonyy'),3,5)` = `to_char(sysdate,'monyy')`

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;    
DECLARE 
    v_drop_table VARCHAR2(50); 
    v_go int := 0;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN
        (
        SELECT lower(table_name) as table_name
        FROM user_tables 
        WHERE LOWER(table_name) LIKE 'mpiat_after_bs_%'
        )
    LOOP  
        v_go: = 0;
        IF rec.table_name =  'mpiat_after_bs_' || to_char(sysdate,'monyy') || '_t'
        THEN 
            v_drop_table := 'DROP TABLE ' || rec.table_name;
            v_go: = 1;
        ELSEIF rec.table_name =  'mpiat_after_bs_ebi_' || to_char(sysdate,'monyy') || '_t'
        THEN
            v_drop_table := 'DROP TABLE ' || rec.table_name;
            v_go: = 1;
        END IF; 

        IF v_go = 1
        THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_drop_table);
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_drop_table;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

*Note* Any of you regular answerers spot typos, feel free to correct me

Comment: It didn't work. I also tried IF-ELSE statement. Still cannot read the table name that is concatenated.

Comment: I corrected all the typos already, but still it didn't delete the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following on your SELECT section after FOR rec IN

```
SELECT LOWER(table_name) AS table_name
```